# Error while running react app on physical device when it is already plugged-in

Tags: react-native, adb

I have a problem with running react apps on my Android physical device when I already plug it in[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSNPq.png).. Plus, I tried everything but "adb devices" still recieved an empty list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0TeY.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happen many time with our devices

> revoke for certificate from android setting and switch off and on
>   developer mode

its may happen if your sim card is not inserted they ask you to please enter the sim card to switch on the developer mode. let me know if you still facing the issue don't forgot to allow permission after revoking certificate from your device.

Comment: Hi @jatin.7744, the issue still remains the same, this solution cannot be afforded

Comment: Okay I check your ScreenShots have you try by changing the cable because I face this issue many time.